# Upload Wicked generated PDF to AWS S3 in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, wicked-pdf

I am generating invoices as PDFs and want to upload them directly to S3.

I am using Wicked-PDF and the official AWS SDK.

```
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'aws-sdk-s3', '~> 1'
```

Now I create the PDF:

```
pdf = render_to_string pdf: "some_file_name", template: "invoices/download", encoding: "UTF-8"
```

And want to upload it:

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: ENV['AWS_REGION'])
obj = s3.bucket('bucket-development').object('Filename')
obj.upload_file(pdf)
```

The error I get:

```
ArgumentError: string contains null byte
```

If I store the PDF first to a defined path and use the save_path it works:

```
save_path = Rails.root.join('public','filename.pdf')
File.open(save_path, 'wb') do |file|
 file << pdf
end
```

But I would like to upload he temporary PDF directly to S3 without saving the PDF first to my public folder.

Answer (score 3):

The `upload_file` method from AWS S3 SDK is working with files - [see the method's description](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3/Object.html#upload_file-instance_method).

For uploading an object from memory, you should use the `put` method - see the method's description in the 2nd way of uploading [on this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpRuby.html)